# What are the major changes at the Survival level?

Tags: fallout-4

I am playing the game in "normal" level, but I am getting to the point where the game starts to be a little bit easy and I want to increase difficulty to Survival.

I was wondering what are the major changes at the Survival level?

Comment: Would like to research before answering,but survival mode insinuates features such as ammo having weight, a requirement to eat and drink,and needing a doctor to heal crippled limbs. It was originally featured as a seperate mode in new vegas, to add realism.

Comment: In NV, companions would be permadead if knocked out. Im told that feature has not been brought across

Comment: New Vegas' survival mode also added a requirement to stay hydrated by drinking and rested by sleeping, didn't it? Was that brought across?